# Avoid open video file after playblast

Tags: maya, mel, pymel

I'm finishing a script that playblasts several pieces of animation into different movie files. It works fine but I'd like it to NOT open all the video files once it is done playblasting them.

Can't find that option even inside maya playblast options itself...  Any light on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the viewer flag to false, are you doing playblast via code ? if so check this [doc](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/playblast.html#flagviewer)

Comment: That 's it! thank you.  It was there all the time, as most things. I'm sorry I overlooked it.  Thank you.